# Embed PowerBI without iFrames. UserOwnsData

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, powerbi

We have a working solution based in the UserOwnsData code provided by MS for embbeding PowerBI into HTML pages. It embeds a PowerBI report using an iframe.

Is there a method to embed PowerBI without using an iframe and let it render directly to an HTML element?

We have used other BI tools, and they allow for iFrame free embedded, which is much quicker and allows for more customisation which is why we want this.

This is the base code we are using: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20organization [image]

Comment: The embedded item is rendered in a `<div>` element. See [the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20organization/UserOwnsData/Views/Home/Embed.cshtml).

Comment: While that is correct, what is placed inside of the div is an iframe. I've added a picture to clarify.

Comment: The `iframe` inside the `<div>` **IS** the Power BI element. Are you really asking how to change the HTML content served by Power BI Service? That's way out of your control.

Comment: No, I'm asking how to make PBI render this inline, instead of using an iframe. Iframes have a lot of overhead and are harder to control and interact with clientside. I've built solutions from other BI vendors that offer this flexibility.